# How to check whether host(server) is available or not in iOS with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ios5, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking in my App for communicating with server. How can i check whether my host(server) is available or not, i should check this before i am sending a request to server.

Comment: i think that manage AFN it self dont warty about it. if that host name not available that fire uncessful block and put there nslog with NSError object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AFNetworking 2.0 that provide method like below you can check instead of using Reachability class.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

}
```

After set start-monitoring in to `viewDidLoad` you can check any where in to class using Bellow Method.

```
 if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]) 
 {
   NSLog(@"IS REACHABILE");
 } 
 else 
 {
   NSLog(@"NOT REACHABLE");
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't check whether a specific host is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
if ([reach isReachable]) {
// Reachable
if ([reach isReachableViaWiFi]) {
    // On WiFi
}
} else {
// Isn't reachable

[reach setReachableBlock:^(Reachability *reachblock)
{
    // Now reachable
}];

[reach setUnreachableBlock:^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Now unreachable
}];
}
```

OR
You can do like this:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
[client setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable) {
    // Not reachable
} else {
    // Reachable
}

if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi) {
    // On wifi
}
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.operationQueue;

// This block is automatically invoked every time the network status changes 
[self.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            // we need to notify a delegete when internet connection is lost.
            // use this delegate to notify the user. 
            //[delegate internetConnectionLost];
            NSLog(@"No Internet Connection");
            break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"Host available through WIFI");
            break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"Host available through 3G");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unkown network status");
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
    }
}];
[self.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```